# Are Toshiba SDHC cards good for Canon DSLR cameras?

Tags: canon, dslr, memory-card, sdhc

I was going through the SDHC cards available in the market and found a really cheap card from a website offering discounted camera and photo gear. I did go through the mostly recommended San Disk SDHC cards, but would you guys suggest me to go for this Toshiba SDHC card? I haven't really come across any reviews about Toshiba memory cards. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

My intentions are to use it for HD videos mostly.

Comment: Just FYI, there seem to be a number of indicators that that site is a bit shady. I'd double-check. For one thing: based in _Gibraltar_. But beyond that, all reviews of the site I can find are _very_ glowing but also posted with the past month, and searching turns up a large number of "planted" blog posts and search-engine-optimization drivel also within the past month. That, combined with prices you describe as "really cheap", make me skeptical. I'm not saying it's necessarily a scam, but I'd sure triple-check.

Comment: Yes indeed, I was and still am very skeptical about the website. To be honest, I was planning to buy my DSLR camera from there soonish.  Still doubtful whether I should or not take the risk after all its not a small lump of money involved.

Comment: I once lost 279 pounds purchasing a computer parts on a "cheap" website thinking that I would get to save something like 30 pounds compared to other sites. I **never** buy from websites with no respectable reputation after that. I end up paying 299 pounds on another reputable website for what I originally wanted to buy, totaling 578 pounds for what should have been 299 pounds.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and unlink the web site in question. I don't think sending traffic there is really the point. :)

Comment: Also worth noting that even if the company delivers on the cards, it's possible that they're pirated. False-label SD cards are quite common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toshiba is a reputable company that does put out quality products. At one time they have even had claims to fame for the fastest SD cards([source](http://www.dpreview.com/news/1009/10090305toshibauhsisdhc.asp)). If you are looking for the cheapest of the cheap, I do not know why you are necessarily asking this question. They are not a popular brand of memory cards, so you will not find many reviews(if any). **If you are concerned with speed and reliability, and not price, I would recommend Sandisk, Transcend, Kingston, or Lexar.**

Comment: Yup, looks like its gonna be Kingston for me :).

Comment: You could also try getting the Toshiba cards (if you're truly set on them) from Amazon - though I got some very cheap Transcend 16GB Class 10 SD cards from Amazon recently.

Comment: Was that SD or SDHC card?